# replace multiple values in Excel 2016 using VBA

Tags: vba

I am confused pls help me to solve this.
 How do I find & replace multiple values in Excel 2016 specially replace some words in some cells with CHR character like Webdings Symbols and so on.
exactly I wanna replace a code like H1, J3 , L1, or ... with these characters ❶ ❷ ❹ ❸ ❺ ❻ ❼ ❽ ❾ ❿
Please HELP.
Thnks

Comment: Do you want to process a **single cell** or more than one cell??

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer:

Make sure you have the "Developer" tab available (google it if haven't got it!)

Set "Use relative references" if you find it appropriate.
Then click "Record a macro" and do ONE search and replace.
Stop the recording.

Hold CTRL and press F11 and the VB Editor pops up.

In there you will find the macro you just recorded.
You will recognize the data you searched for, and what you replaced with.
All you have to do now is copy and change the code in it for it to replace  the other things you asked for.

Comment: Could U pls try it once?

Comment: I found these characters as part of the Webdings2 font. The "1" is CHAR(117) in that font, and the numbers increase from there.  If you put =CHAR(117) in a cell, it will show "u", until you **change the font of that cell** to Webdings2.  You might have something like that going on.

Comment: Yeah , But Its some how different . but I can do and appreciate my friend.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions - it only encourages users to ask more of them.